# Determine orthogonal projection on column space of given matrix

Tags: matrices, projection

I have been given this problem to solve for my next lecture. 
I tried to solve it and this is what i came up with. I need someone to check this, is it correct answer.

Problem: Find linear operator of orthogonal projection $$P:R^{3}->R^{3}$$ which projects onto column space of matrix B. 
$$ B =  \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
 0&1 \\ 
 2&0 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) $$

a)Find matrix of linear operator P, in the base of space R3. Choose basis vectors as you want.
b) Find image of vector b=[-4 3 4]^t with P
c) Without doing any calculation find eiganvalues and eigenvectors for P

Here is my atempt to solve this problem.

a) We know that linear operator P projects onto column space of B, so 
$$Im(P)=Lin{ {   \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix},   \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} } }$$ 
For the kernel of P. I think that every other vector should be projected to zero. So i found a orthogonal subspace spanned by vector  $$ \begin{bmatrix}
-2\\ 
2\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$$
So $$ KerP=  Lin \begin{bmatrix}
-2\\ 
2\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} $$

If i choose these vectors to be basis for R3 and represent the P by this base it's matrix will be:

$$ P=  \begin{matrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&1  & 0\\ 
0 &  0& 0
\end{matrix} $$

b)  P*b 
c) Obviously the eigenvalues are 1,1 and 0. 
And the eigenvectors are easly calculated without touching the pen it's the standard (canonical) base for R3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the point of the problem is that you can claim part b is stated relative to your chosen basis, nor part c. To get part b you would have to express vector $\vec b$, assumed relative to the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of your basis, project with your $P$, then express the result in terms of the original basis. Thus if
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-2\\0&1&2\\2&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Is the matrix whose columns are your basis vectors, then you need to compute
$$\begin{align}VPV^{-1}\vec b&=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-2\\0&1&2\\2&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac19&-\frac19&\frac49\\\frac49&\frac59&-\frac29\\-\frac29&\frac29&\frac19\end{bmatrix}\vec b\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac59&\frac49&\frac29\\\frac49&\frac59&-\frac29\\\frac29&-\frac29&\frac89\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-4\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$ to get the projection in part b. Note that as an intermediate result in our calculation we found $P$ relative to the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.
The columns of $V$ above are eigenvectors of $P$ with eigenvalues $1$, $1$, and $0$ relative to the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ by construction.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But in the problem says i can choose whatever basis i wont, and to chose the best or smartest basis possible. So i think there is no better basis than this, because the matrix is so simple. Can you tell me, with this regard, is my solution valid?

Comment: Also if i change the basis, could i simply represent b in my new basis and then P*b?

Comment: What is your [numeric] answer to part b? If you said $$\begin{bmatrix}-4\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ the answer clearly wouldn't be right in either basis.

Comment: I think i must represent b in my new base and then i can simply do P*b?

Comment: I suppose the solution in your cross comment would be OK, with an explanation that the answer is relative to your new basis. That is pretty much what my arithmetic did except that it then transformed back to the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Then i come with  [65 -33 0]^T as solution. That is in new base.Can you check for me please the eigenvector part? It's really confusing because i could easly do this problem with the formula you stated. But this "ideal base" is just a bit confusing.

Comment: @techno For part (c) you’re again being too cavalier about which basis you’re working in. Relative to the basis that you’ve chosen, the coordinate tuples $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ indeed represent eigenvectors of $T$, but those tuples don’t represent the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$. Indeed, none of the standard basis vectors lies in either $\operatorname{col}(B)$ or its orthogonal complement, so they can’t possibly be eigenvectors of $T$.

Comment: Please show your calculations for part b so we can find your error.

Comment: Yeah, but that's the part of the problem. I didn't made it up. Thank you for your time and patience. If i transfer b to "ideal basis" i get [1 -2 2] and if i then multiply it by P. So P*b= [0 -1 2]. But that confuses me a bit. Because you get same result as I did. And my calculation was in this base, and your in canonical.  ps: for eigenvectors i forgot to say that they will be standard basis if we include the zero vector.

Comment: Right, you should get $$\vec b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$ in the new basis; I assume that what you wrote is a typo. And then $$P\vec b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ in the new basis and then $$P\vec b=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$ back in the original basis. And in your last sentence I assume you meant "the vector with eigenvalue zero", i.e. the third column of $V$ from my post.

Comment: Yeah, i have mistake it's [1 -1 2]^T. But it's boging me again. Because, we have P in our new base not canonical. And vector b also. How the product of Pb doesnt get in our new base but in canonical?    Yeah, for zero eigenvalue we get [0 0 1]^T as eigenvector. ps: thank you soooo much <3   Edit:  Now it's clear to me, sorry for consuming your time to explain me such banal stuff. Thank you! I will ace the exam!